# Adding random edges in a graph generated using BOOST graphical library

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I would like to add random edges in my graph, which is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>                   // for std::pair
#include <algorithm> 
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include "boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp"
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

    typedef adjacency_list< listS, vecS, undirectedS > undigraph;

    int const N = read_int_from_user("Number of vertices: ");   

    undigraph g(N);

    // add some edges,             // #1
    for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j != N; ++j)
        {
            add_edge(i, j, g);
        }
    }
    write_graphviz(cout, g);
}
```

The lines following `#1` do that.

But as you can see, there exists 8 edges from each vertex but I Would like to have only 4 to the max and would like to connect all the vertices in a random way and most importantly there can be only 4 valencies from each vertex. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where do the numbers `8` and `4` come from?!

Comment: I would just like to remark that you seem to be *very* lax about paying attention to any of the details... It's not "BOOST" but "Boost", and it's not a "graphical library", but a *graph* library. It's a minor nitpick, but you're obviously struggling with this project, and I would like to caution you that if you don't make a big effort to get the small details right, you will find putting everything together a formidable challenge.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes indeed I am struggling a lot with this project and my deadline is very near. And I would definitely work on my basic skills more and would consider your word of caution. Thanks a ton for the advice.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If the answer below is the one you wanted, accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I said "ordered pair" when I meant "unordered pair"!  Hope the rephrasing is clearer now.

What you need to do is sample without replacement from the set of all *unordered* pairs of nonnegative integers that are < N.  Since it's much easier for a computer to represent an ordered pair than an unordered pair, the usual way to produce this set is to produce all ordered pairs in which the first element is less than the second:

```
vector<pair<int, int> > pairs;

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j) {
        pairs.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
    }
}
```

So e.g. if N = 4, the set of possible edges to consider is:

```
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
1, 2
1, 3
2, 3
```

A nice way to sample from this set once you have it is to use [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. As i can see, that code above creates a `pair(i,j)`. But it isn't possible to use pairs in `add_edges(i,j,g)` as it requires separate values of i and j. So is it possible to separate the pairs before I can use them in `add_edges()`

Comment: @Kishorepandey: Of course you can get both parts out of a `pair` after making one, otherwise it wouldn't be much use would it! :-P  A `pair<int, int>` is just a `struct` containing 2 members, `first` and `second`.  So e.g. `cout << "The first pair is " << pairs[0].first << ", " << pairs[0].second << endl;`

Comment: I tried it, but I am not getting the output as above. I am getting all the edges like: `(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3),(1,1)..and so on until(4,4) for N=4`. But I would really like to have something like you have mentioned above.

Comment: My code is something like this `vector<pair<int, int> >pairs; pairs.push_back(make_pair(i, j));add_edge(pairs[0].first, pairs[0].first , g);` Am I doing something wrong over here?

Comment: @Kishorepandey: It looks like you're adding the edge to the graph inside the same loop as you're building the vector of all possible edges...  You should (1) build the vector of all possible edges, then (2) reservoir sample some number (say k) edges from this vector to produce another vector containing the random edges to actually include, then finally (3) add those edges to the graph using `add_edges()`.

Comment: @Kishorepandey: There may be a way to do it using only 1 (or maybe even 0) temporary vectors of edges instead of 2, but the algorithm in my previous comment is simple and will work.

Comment: I am extremely sorry but, i am pretty much new to c++, I do understand what you mean but, I am finding it really difficult to implement it.

Comment: @Kishorepandey: No need to apologise :) But you need to have some programming experience (even in another language is OK) to tackle something like this.  I don't see any loops in your second-to-last comment, so I can't really tell if you're doing things in the right order.

Comment: I will do one thing, I will re-post another question, with my exact requirements and things I have done so far. :) So that things would be more clear to the viewer.